# How to make a flash loaded check in Chrome?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, externalinterface

I launch an Actionscript function through javascript via ExternalInterface.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("/img/tts_langx.swf", "tts_lang", "1", "1", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

However, when flash doesn't load, or player isn't available, everything breaks. So I want to check for flash and if it is not loaded for some reason kill that part of the process only.

I make the check through:

```
function thisMovie(movieName) {
 if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
     return window[movieName];
 } else {
     return document[movieName];
 }
}
```

and then I make:

```
if(thisMovie('myFlash').theActionscriptFunction==null){...}else{}
```

which is a very ugly way, but works in firefox and safari, not in Chrome.

How can i make this check in the best way and know for all the browsers, if flash is available for functions in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way would be to change the Flash movie in this manner:

When the movie loads (in the load listener in AS), add this

```
if(ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call(flashReady);
}
```

and in the javascript, have a function called flashReady which does the thing it needs to

```
function flashReady() {
    //Your awesome function body here
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I have my function fire on click, so it has plenty of time to load and be available, yet fails. Also, in case there is no flash player, i have no way of knowing and continuing without the flash part.

Comment: Exactly. So you can set a flag called `flashAvailable` from the `flashReady` function. Then before you attempt to call the AS3 function, check the flag